# How to toggle group visibility in QGIS using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I've tried this, but it doesn't work out.

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group1 = root.insertGroup(0, "PGB")

legend = i.legendInterface()
legend.isGroupVisible(group1)
legend.setGroupVisible(group1, False)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're close! The `setGroupVisible` function requires *(int, boolean)* as parameters (i.e. the integer you provided for your group as `0`). Try the following:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group1 = root.insertGroup(0, "PGB")

legend = iface.legendInterface()
legend.setGroupVisible(0, False)
```

Comment: @Steven - Most welcome buddy, glad it works =)